# Kendo MVVM custom binding for a click in checkbox

Tags: jquery, mvvm, kendo-ui

So, I want to use iCheck for my checkboxes, but that will require custom binding for that.  Kendo MVVM, knockout, or whatever other js libraries.

I almost have my custom binding perfect, but it doesn't trigger on a click of a checkbox.  If I change the input from a checkbox to text input, the click custom binding works great.

```
kendo.data.binders.myICheck = kendo.data.Binder.extend({
    init: function (element, bindings, options) {
        //call the base constructor
        kendo.data.Binder.fn.init.call(this, element, bindings, options);
        var that = this;
        //listen for the change event of the element
        $(that.element).on("click", function () {
            that.click(); //call the change function
        });
    },
    click: function () {
        this.bindings["myICheck"].set(false);
    },
    refresh: function () {
        var value = this.bindings["myICheck"].get();
        if (value) {
            $(this.element).iCheck('check');
        } else {
            $(this.element).iCheck('uncheck');
        }
    }
});
```

HTML is

```
input indeterminate="false" data-bind="myICheck: rememberUserInfo" class="check">
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, figured it out, iClick has it's own events:
I need to use ifChagned or ifClicked

```
 $(that.element).on("ifClicked", function () {
```

http://fronteed.com/iCheck/